# Remove select options based on button click in angular js

Tags: angularjs

In my app i have a select html which has following options
"Addition","Deletion","Duplicate","Member Duplicate"

Above drop down  page is common for both add and edit screen. As of now if we come from any addition click or edit click drop-down has all options. (Note: drop-down binds at the time of loading page itself. we will show/hide depending on click)

As per new requirement I need to remove all other options except "Addition" in addition click and remove "Addition" option in edit click.

select html:

```
<select name="ReasonID" required ng-model="member.ReasonID" class="form-control" ng-options="reason.ID as reason.Description for reason in reasons |orderBy: reason.Description"></select>
```

Js

```
$scope.manageMember = function (member) {
  $scope.showGrid = false; 
  $scope.showForm = true;
  reset();
  $scope.memberTemp = member;
  angular.extend($scope.member, member); };
```

Please let me know if you need more details from my end.

Comment: select html is:

Comment: <select  class="form-control" ng-model="accountsel" ng-change="getMembership()" ng-options="account.CustomerName for account in accounts | orderBy: account.CustomerName" >
                        </select>

Comment: When you are referring to addition click what does that mean. Do you mean that when a user selects addition from select box then all other option for the same select box should be removed?

Comment: Would you like to remove it from DOM or only want to hide.

Comment: No. There are 2 buttons.. on click of "Add" button then I need to hide/remove all options from select html except "Addtion" option.  On click of "edit" then I need to hide/remove only "Addition" option from select html.

Comment: I belive hide will work. if i remove then I need to rebind it

Comment: Prameela. Can you show me the controller code?

Comment: store with array and remove add

Comment: $scope.manageMember = function (member) {
         $scope.showGrid = false;
         $scope.showForm = true;

         reset();
         $scope.memberTemp = member;
         angular.extend($scope.member, member);
         
     };

Comment: please let me know how to do so

Comment: manageMember function will be called for both add and edit button click.

Comment: If I good understand you have options "Addition", "Deletion", "Duplicate", "Member Duplicate".. But in your ng-repeat i see customersName. Could you explain more?

Comment: How can you know the function calling is addition or not  when I click addition? did you pass any param or flag?

Comment: this is select html: <select name="ReasonID" required ng-model="member.ReasonID" class="form-control" ng-options="reason.ID as reason.Description for reason in reasons | orderBy: reason.Description"></select>

Comment: when we call from additon button click.. member object is undefined. from edit click we will get member object

Comment: Is it possible to use filter option? if so how to pass it from controller in above method?

Comment: @prameelarani . please take a look at my answer. I hope it will be works for you

Comment: @prameelarani I have update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update :**

Here the full sample code and working demo with dummy data.

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <select name="ReasonID" required ng-model="member.ReasonID" class="form-control" ng-options="reason.ID as reason.Description for reason in reasons |orderBy: reason.Description"></select>
    <br/>
   <input type="button" ng-click="manageMember(undefined)" value="add"/>
    <input type="button" ng-click="manageMember('bla bla bla')" value="edit"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.reasons = [{ID:1,Description :"Addition"},  {ID:2,Description :"Deletion"},{ID:3,Description :"Duplicate"},{ID:4,Description :"Member Duplicate"}];

var reasonsTemp =angular.copy($scope.reasons); 

$scope.manageMember = function (member) {
console.log(reasonsTemp)
  $scope.reasons=reasonsTemp;// assign global object to model
  $scope.showGrid = false; 
  $scope.showForm = true;  
  $scope.memberTemp = member;   
  var EditArray=[];
   for(var i = 0 ; $scope.reasons.length>i;i++)
   {
    if($scope.reasons[i].Description === ($scope.memberTemp == undefined ? "Addition" : "bla bla bla"))// condition for is this addition or not
     {
     EditArray = $scope.reasons[i];
     break;   
     }     
     else // if is it not addition, then addition only offect that object. because we were already assigned original value globally
     {   
      if($scope.reasons[i].Description!=="Addition")
      {
        EditArray.push($scope.reasons[i])
      }
     }
   }
   $scope.reasons=EditArray;
   console.log($scope.reasons);
 }
}
```

[**Working Demo On console window**](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/28955/)

Comment: this is how we call manage member function: add button:  <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="manageMember()" ng-show="accountsel"
                         >
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Member
</button>
                </div>

Comment: edit button click (Edit is an image) :   <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="manageMember(auditmembership)" >
                                                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true" ></span> 
                                                       </button>

Comment: without passing parameter value `auditmembership()`. how it will be work??

Comment: And what is the value of `auditmembership`?

Comment: that's why I wrote this code `$scope.memberTemp == undefined ? "Addition" : "bla bla bla` . please read my full inline comments and check it out Rani

Comment: auditmembership is a model in edit page which has all values for preselect.. Since we are not passing values inside managemember function'member' is undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130926/discussion-between-ramesh-rajendran-and-prameela-rani).

Comment: let me try ur solution once. Please give me 5minutes

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
HTML

```
  <select ng-model="selectedOption">
   <option ng-show="reason.show" ng-repeat="reason.ID as reason.Description for reason in reasons |orderBy: reason.Description">{{reason.ID}}</option> 
  </select>
```

JS

```
$scope.manageMember = function (member) {
 $scope.showGrid = false; 
 $scope.showForm = true;
 reset();
 $scope.memberTemp = member;   
 angular.extend($scope.member, member);
 if(member){
    for(var i = 0 ; $scope.reasons.length>i;i++)
     { 
       $scope.reasons[i].show = true;
       if($scope.reasons[i].ID == "Addition"){$scope.reasons[i].show = false;}
     }
   }else{
       for(var i = 0 ; $scope.reasons.length>i;i++)
     { 
       $scope.reasons[i].show = false;
       if($scope.reasons[i].ID == "Addition"){$scope.reasons[i].show = true;}
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: @prameela, please let me know that "Addition" is in your ID or Desrciption.

Comment: Hi dude,  your answer is just  awesome . but remove this code `$scope.reasons=reasonsTemp from your answer `. because some one find  this line from my answer.

Comment: Ok @RameshRajendran i thought u used the same (first five lines) as given in question, so took from here, it will no matter for me as i didn't use this variable. BTW thanks to remind :)

Comment: Why you using `angular.extend($scope.member, member);
` here?

Comment: Because OP wants to copying properties in  $scope.member, may be she is using this variable in somewhere in view. It will not reflect my code so did not remove it. But in case of undefined (member) may be it will be a error, will it?

Comment: all properties are set properly but select options are empty n the UI.. i have given select html as follows:

Comment: <select ng-model="member.ReasonID" class="form-control">
   <option ng-repeat="reason.ID as reason.Description for reason in reasons |orderBy: reason.Description">{{member.ReasonID}}</option> 
  </select>

Comment: @prameelarani what if you use

<select ng-model="member.ReasonID" class="form-control"> <option ng-repeat="reason.ID as reason.Description for reason in reasons |orderBy: reason.Description">{{reason.Description}}</option> </select>

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two buttons as,

```
<input type="button" ng-click="toAdd=true">Add</input>
<input type="button" ng-click="toAdd=false">Edit</input>
```

And the select box code should be like,

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption">
   <option ng-show="toAdd">Addition</option>
   <option ng-show="!toAdd">Deletion</option>
   <option ng-show="!toAdd">Duplicate</option>
   <option ng-show="!toAdd">Member Duplicate</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: for better understanding I gave options that are getting binded. actually all these comes from database not hardcoded

Comment: this is how we bind select html: function getData() {
         memAuditFactory.getData().then(function (response) {
             $scope.reasons = response.data.Reasons;
         });
     }

Comment: Is it possible to use filter option? if so how to pass it from controller in above method?