# How to remove all values from dropdown except one which is selected from another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have three dropdowns:-

```
    <select clas="col-md-3" ng-model="a.userList" ng-change="selectValues(a.userList)">
        <option>AX</option>
        <option>AF</option>
        <option>AM</option>
        <option>BX</option>
        <option>BF</option>
        <option>BM</option>
        <option>CX</option>
        <option>CF</option>
        <option>CM</option>
        <option>DX</option>
        <option>DF</option>
        <option>DM</option>
</select>
<select clas="col-md-3" ng-model="a.userCode">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
        <option>D</option>
</select>
<select clas="col-md-3" ng-model="a.userId">
        <option>X</option>
        <option>F</option>
        <option>M</option>
</select>
```

what I want is when user select `AX` then from other two dropdowns A and X got selected respectively and all the other values got removed from that two dropdowns.

My directive Code:-

```
               scope.selectValues = function(userList){
                    switch(userList){
                        case "AX" : scope.a.userCode = "A";
                                    scope.a.userId = "X";
                                    break;
                        case "AF" : scope.a.userCode = "A";
                                    scope.a.userId = "F";
                                    break;
                        case "AM" : scope.a.userCode = "A";
                                    scope.a.userId = "M";
                                    break;
                    };

                };
```

On the above code I am able to select the particular value which I want to select but not able to remove all the other values from the two dropdowns. Can anyone tell me how to remove the values from dropdowns.

Comment: have tried basic things like $('#selectId').find('option[value!="'+removeItemVal+'"]').remove();

Comment: @Mujthaba Ibrahim, should I apply it in each case?

Comment: I'am not good in angularjs. if you put a code like that and it is working, then you need to add it for every case

Comment: actually the cod is not working, I think there is some angularJs/jquery error.

Comment: Try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217869/remove-select-options-based-on-button-click-in-angular-js

Answer (score 1):

You should put your options in the scope!

**JS**

```
scope.userList = ["AX","AF", "AM", "BX", "BF"];
//Obviously put all of your options in this array also for the other selects
scope.userCode = [....];
scope.userId = [....];
```

**HTML**

> ng-options is what you need

```
 <select class="col-md-3" ng-model="a.userList"
     ng-options="option for option in topUserList track by $index"
     ng-change="selectValues(a.userList)"></select>
```

**JS**

```
 scope.selectValues = function(userList){
        scope.a.userCode = userList.charAt(0);
        scope.a.userId = userList.charAt(1);
        scope.userCode = [scope.a.userCode];
        scope.userId = [scope.a.userId];

 };
```